# Is there a log of Pi reboots?

Tags: raspbian, boot, logfiles

Does the Pi keep a log of its restarts? I found a good record of "Booting ..." in `/var/log/messages` in one of my Pi's, but in another Pi, `/var/log/messages` shows only `rsyslogd` entries. Both Pi's are Pi 3 Model B and both are running Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie). Is there a way to increase the amount of detail logged to `messages`?  Or is there another log that saves the date & time of restarts?

(My Pi's are running fine and I'm hoping a record of restarts or "Booting ..." can tell me when there were power outages)

Answer (score 4):

`last` shows a listing of last logged in users.

`last -x` should show what you want, although not directly.

`last -x` shows "the system shutdown entries and run level changes"

```
pi       pts/0        10.1.2.100       Mon Jan 11 17:32   still logged in
pi       pts/0        10.1.2.100       Sat Jan  9 18:06 - 13:08 (1+19:01)
pi       pts/0        fe80::1ca4:d038: Fri Jan  8 21:31 - 15:37  (18:06)
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.4.83-v7l+      Fri Jan  8 21:31   still running
pi       tty1                          Fri Jan  8 21:30   still logged in
pi       tty7         :0               Fri Jan  8 21:30   still logged in
reboot   system boot  5.4.83-v7l+      Thu Jan  1 10:00   still running
shutdown system down  5.4.79-v7l+      Fri Jan  8 21:30 - 10:00 (-18635+10:30)
pi       pts/0        10.1.2.100       Wed Jan  6 17:28 - 21:28 (2+04:00)
pi       pts/0        fe80::1ca4:d038: Tue Jan  5 17:36 - 14:29  (20:52)
pi       pts/0        10.1.2.100       Tue Jan  5 10:06 - 12:22  (02:16)
pi       tty7         :0               Mon Jan  4 16:29 - 21:28 (4+04:59)
pi       tty1                          Mon Jan  4 16:29 - down  (4+05:01)
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.4.79-v7l+      Mon Jan  4 16:29 - 21:30 (4+05:01)
reboot   system boot  5.4.79-v7l+      Thu Jan  1 10:00 - 21:30 (18635+10:30)
```

EDIT

If you are happy with the limited reporting in `messages` the following script will show boots. This only shows recent attempts (default 4 weeks). I had a similar script working on `kern.log` but adapted this to `/var/log/messages` although the results are similar.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Print login history
for logf in $(ls /var/log/messages*.gz | sort -rV) ; do zcat $logf | grep -E "Booting" ; done
# Include most recent
for logf in $(ls /var/log/messages* | sort -rV) ; do cat $logf | grep -E "Booting" ; done
```

On my Pi this shows:-

```
Dec 14 16:11:24 MilliwaysPi4 kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Dec 19 11:36:37 MilliwaysPi4 kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Dec 19 12:53:25 MilliwaysPi4 kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Dec 21 15:00:57 MilliwaysPi4 kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Jan  4 16:28:36 MilliwaysPi4 kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Jan  8 21:30:25 MilliwaysPi4 kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
```

Answer (score 2):

The **systemd journal** is only transient stored in a `/run/log/journal/` which is located in RAM and lost on every reboot. You can make its storage persistent on the SD Card so you can also query old boots. In `/usr/share/doc/systemd/README.Debian` you will find:

> To enable persistent logging, create /var/log/journal:
>
> `mkdir -p /var/log/journal`
> `systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal`
>
> systemd will make the journal files owned by the "systemd-journal" group and add an ACL for read permissions for users in the "adm" group. To grant a user read access to the system journal, add them to one of the two groups. This will allow you to look at previous boot logs with e. g.
>
> `journalctl -b -1`
>
> If you enable persistent logging, consider uninstalling rsyslog or any other system-log-daemon, to avoid logging everything twice.

Comment: `system.journal` seem to be binary. How do you read the contents to query old boots?

Comment: @user3217032 Look at my answer. The example shows the boot (`-b`) before the current boot (`-1`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks above for info on `dmesg` and `last` commands. But what I found worked best was viewing `var/log/messages` and searching for the keyword "Booting":
`less /var/log/messages | grep Booting` and `less /var/log/messages.1 | grep Booting`.
For older archived `messages`, e.g., `messages.2.gz`, `zcat /var/log/messages.2.gz | grep Booting` worked nicely.